# Deserialize a JSON Schema with JSON.Net

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization, jsonschema

I want to deserialize this schema using JSON.Net.

```
{ 
  "color" : { 
    "type" : "String", 
    "description" : "What color do you want your taco", 
    "required" : false, 
    "default" : "Green", 
    "options" : [ "Green", "Blue", "Red"]
  },
  "include_beans" : { 
    "type"  : "Boolean", 
    "description" : "Do you want beans on your taco", 
    "required" : false, 
    "default" : false 
  }, 
  "pounds"  : { 
    "type" : "Double", 
    "description" : "How  many pounds of meat do you want?", 
    "required"  : false, 
    "default" : 0.1 
  },  
  "count" : { 
    "type"  : "Integer", 
    "description" : "How  many tacos would you like?", 
    "required"  : false, 
    "default" : 0.0 
  }
}
```

Notice that each property has the same structure.  What I want to end up with is a `Dictionary<string, TacoProperty>`, where `TacoProperty` is defined as:

```
public class TacoProperty
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public bool required { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "default")]
    public string defaultValue { get; set; }
    public List<string> options { get; set; }
}
```

The keys into the dictionary should be "color", "include_beans" etc., and all the `TacoProperty`s should be the values.

Comment: So what did you try (knowing the target type), and what didn't work when you tried it? Json.NET is fully capable of deserializing directly to `Dictionary<string,X>`.

Comment: Possibly because there is no problem presented, only a task and all the information is available to try something (which would either work or result in an error/issue).

Comment: E.g. Including the self-posted answer here, for "this is what I have, and it works, but it doesn't seem very elegant" would constitute *some* problem. It's very important to establish a particular problem.

Comment: For future reference, I believe that a question like this (where you have some code written, and it works, but maybe not the most elegant code) is better suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Good to know.  Thanks for the tip.  I only used the Q and A format because I didn't know if there was a better way, but it might be useful info for others regardless.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Json.NET can deserialize the data directly:

```
var tacoProperties =
       JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IDictionary<string, TacoProperty>>(json);
```

Comment: Thank you.  This is much more elegant than my way.  I had no idea it would automatically use the Path as the key.

Comment: This is what SO is about, yet I'm getting downvoted for trying to learn a better way to do something.  Thanks again.